# Python3 - How can I iterate and remove the entry in CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before, I had a list of nodes. So, I easily iterate, and if the command runs successfully remove the entry and after 1 hr write back the remaining ones to the file. Instead of 1 variable for 1 command, now I have 4 variables that I cannot put on the list. After some research, I find out CSV is the best solution rather than JSON to append files. How can I iterate and remove the entry in CSV as I did it list?

```
stop_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
while list_file:
        list_iterate = list_file.copy()
        for i in list_iterate:
            cmd = f'some bash cmd'
            value = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8").strip()
            if value == '0':
                list_file.remove(i)
        if datetime.datetime.now() > stop_time:
            completed = False
            with open("list_file.txt", "w") as file:
               file.write(list_file)
            break
```

Sample CSV

```
cluster1,pool1, abc
cluster1,pool2,bcb
cluster2,pool1,abc
```

Comment: Using a CSV file is only marginally less brittle than using a JSON file. You want to use a mechanism which was designed for simple atomic updates, like an SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a CSV file to a list and then remove from that. Example snippet (modify / extend to include the 1 hour delay etc.):

```py
with open("path/to/inputfile.csv", "r") as infile:
    list_file = infile.readlines()

index = 1
list_file.remove(index)

with open("path/to/outputfile.csv","w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(list_file)
```

Comment: This will not solve my problem. If you notice none of the columns is identical, but whole row is. So, I have had to put logic on the whole row and if satisfy then I have to remove that row and iterate again. And after 1 hr I have to write back to file and try again after 6hr.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I don't get the point of this - can you please add sample input and expected output to your question and tell me when done ?

Comment: In my question, Sample CSV with 4 lines. It could be 100 lines. I have to iterate line by line through for loop and remove the lines if my logic satisfies (need a way to remove the line). And for the remaining lines where my logic not works, I have to write back to files again with left lines.